# Does a high negative concordance imply reproducible features

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, reproducible-research, concordance

Does a high negative(-1) Lin's concordance correlation coefficient(Lins CCC) imply reproducible features ?

I am calculating Lin's CCC of radiomic features between  two different CT scan settings ,  if I get a CCC value of say for example  -1 for one particular feature, does this imply that the feature is perfectly reproducible?

Comment: Please avoid the use of abbreviations that may not be common knowledge

Comment: I don't know, ask @whuber . Anyway an explanation of what the hell do CCC and CT would also be great!

Comment: CCC is concordance correlation coefficient, it's a measure of agreement between bivariate data.  A CCC of 1 implies perfect reproducibility, essentially 1 means that the bivariate data falls on the line of best fit and has a squared ortoginal distance of 0 from the line of slope 1 ie y=x  for all pairs of data.  CT is just computed tomography, 3D x Ray